# itemsControl item insertion animation

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, animation, storyboard

i am showing a kind list using `itemsControl` in my windows phone 7 app, but i am very new to `animation` and `storyBoard` etc
so my `itemsControl` is given below

```
    <ItemsControl x:Name="ListContainer">

                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>                        
                            <DataTemplate x:Name="listTemplate">                                
                                    <StackPanel Margin="25,0,0,0" MaxHeight="100">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" FontSize="21"></TextBlock>                            
                                        <Button Name="btn" Tag="{Binding ID}" Content="request" FontSize="21" Width="183" Click="btn_Click" Padding="0"></Button>
                                    </StackPanel>                                
                            </DataTemplate>                            
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    </ItemsControl>
```

now i want to add an `animation` so that whenever an item being adding to this `itemsControl` it (`item`) should be moving from `bottom` to `up` an d than `add`

i googled alot but not found any satiable answer, so if anyone having knowledge about storyboard and animation plZ put an answer      -: thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement such animation you need:                                                     1. Add `TranslateTransform` to an item `StackPanel` and set `Y` to 900;
2. Add event handler to `Loaded` event of the `StackPanel`;
Your XAML now will look like:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ListContainer" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="listTemplate">
                        <StackPanel Margin="25,0,0,0" MaxHeight="100" Loaded="FrameworkElement_OnLoaded">
                            <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform Y="900"/>
                            </StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="21"></TextBlock>
                            <Button Name="btn" Content="request" FontSize="21" Width="183" Padding="0"></Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
```

3. In `Loaded` event handler you need to create a `Storyboard` that is going to move a new item:

```
private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var storyboard = new Storyboard();
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation
                            {
                                From = 900, 
                                To = 0
                            };

        var translatTransform = new TranslateTransform
                                    {
                                        Y = 900
                                    };

        var panel = (StackPanel) sender;
        panel.RenderTransform = translatTransform;

        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, translatTransform);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Y"));
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

Comment: excellent answer !, exactly wat i was looking for
thanks @uer2429991

Answer (score 0):

Now just check out this animation tutorial in blend and apply your own ideas. Doing in blend is a very good for animations.
[Animating a card in windows phone](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kevinash/archive/2011/12/21/flipping-card-animation-for-windows-phone-7-using-expression-blend.aspx)

And for the animation of item control,this works:[Item control animation](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.in/2011/11/when-i-talk-of-mvvm-pattern-people.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20blogspot/dotnetbyexample%20%28.NET%20by%20Example%29&utm_content=Google%20Reader)

Comment: well, its not that i wanted. but thanx for ur answer @max